# Apache Zeppelin Notebook Deployment

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I'm new to ETL development with PySpark and I've been writing my scripts as paragraphs on Apache Zeppelin Notebooks. I was curious what the typical flow was for a deployment process? How are you converting your code from a Zeppelin Notebook to your ETL pipeline?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66433489/15311891
please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that heavily depends on the sort of ETL that you're doing.

If you want to keep the scripts in the notebooks and you just need to orchestrate their execution then you have a couple options:

- Use [Zeppelin's built-in scheduler](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/other_features/cron_scheduler.html)
- Use cron to launch your notebooks via `curl` commands and [Zeppelin's REST API](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/usage/rest_api/notebook.html)

But if you already have an up-and-running workflow management tool like Apache Airflow then you can add new tasks that launch the aforementioned `curl` commands to trigger the notebooks (with Airflow, you can use BashOperator or PythonOperator), but keep in mind that you'll need some workarounds to have a sequential execution of different notes.

One major tech company that's betting heavily on notebooks is Netflix (you can take a look at [this](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/notebook-innovation-591ee3221233)), and they developed a set of tools to improve the effeciency of notebook-based ETL pipelines, like [Commuter](https://github.com/nteract/commuter) and [Papermill](https://papermill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). They're more into Jupyter, so Zeppelin compatibility is still not provided, but the core concepts should be the same when working with Zeppelin.

For more on Netflix' notebook-based pipelines, you can refer to [this article](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/scheduling-notebooks-348e6c14cfd6) shared on their tech blog.

Comment: Thanks @mahdiqb!